# Add static route to one specific address to dhcpd.conf

Tags: route, isc-dhcpd

I want to add a static route to `10.13.0.1/32` via `192.168.178.10` to my `dhcpd.conf` of my dhcpd server. Unfortunately this seems to be insanely complicated.

I tried the following:

```
option static-routes 10.13.0.1 192.168.178.10;
```

However this will add a route to `10.0.0.0/8` via `192.168.178.10` which is undesired.
I also tried:

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;
option ms-classless-static-routes 32, 10, 13, 0, 1, 192, 168, 178, 10;
```

Which results in the dhcpd to no longer start:

```
Feb 13 20:49:30 csh-gw dhcpd[32042]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Feb 13 20:49:30 csh-gw dhcpd[32042]: /var/lib/dhcp//etc/dhcpd.conf line 63: unknown option dhcp.ms-classless-static-routes
Feb 13 20:49:30 csh-gw dhcpd[32042]: option ms-classless-static-routes 32,
Feb 13 20:49:30 csh-gw dhcpd[32042]:         ^
Feb 13 20:49:30 csh-gw dhcpd[31870]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 Server
Feb 13 20:49:30 csh-gw dhcpd[31870]:   please see /var/log/rc.dhcpd.log for details ..failed
```

Googling for this issue did only yield results of adding routes to entire networks including a default gateway, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever try this?

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes 32, 10, 13, 0, 1, 192, 168, 178, 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable 2 different options, because Microsoft uses a different option than the one defined in RFC 3442:

```
# Enable sending of static routes
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of integer 8;
option      ms-classless-static-routes code 249 = array of integer 8;
```

Then define both options, which fortunately use the same syntax in the ISC `dhcpd.conf` file. First the destination IP mask, which will also define how many bytes of the IP need to be given. In your case, for a single IP with a mask of 32, you will give all 4 IP bytes:

```
# Route                             to    10.13.0.1/32 through 192.168.178.10;
#                                       ┌────────────┘
#                                       |  |  | | |   
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes 32,10,13,0,1,           192,168,178,10;
option      ms-classless-static-routes 32,10,13,0,1,           192,168,178,10;
```

For a route to a 24 bit network (all IP between 10.13.0.1 and 10.13.0.255), you give only the 3 bytes for the network. It would look like this:

```
# Route                             to    10.13.0.1/24 through 192.168.178.10;
#                                       ┌────────────┘
#                                       |  |  | |    
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes 24,10,13,0,             192,168,178,10;
option      ms-classless-static-routes 24,10,13,0,             192,168,178,10;
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are most likely wrong. While this may push the desired route to a DHCP client, in my testing the clients will not have a default route anymore.

So before deploying the suggestions, make sure the client network configuration is actually correct!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/436198)

Comment: As I said, the suggestions will likely introduce regressions. That is all what can be said at this point.